# GPT - Non key value ads showing in key valuse ad slots

Tags: javascript, key-value, google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

I have set up Ad Units and Key Values in DFP. I have built the site with the following code based on Google's tutorials:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var googletag = googletag || {};
        googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
        (function() {
            var gads = document.createElement("script");
            gads.async = true;
            gads.type = "text/javascript";
            var useSSL = "https:" == document.location.protocol;
            gads.src = (useSSL ? "https:" : "http:") + "//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js";
            var node =document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
        })();
    </script>
    <script>
        var sitePath = "/test-kv/parent/page"
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            var kvAdSlot = 
                googletag.defineSlot('/00000000' + sitePath, [300, 250], 'kvAd');

                kvAdSlot.addService(googletag.pubads());
                kvAdSlot.setTargeting('key', 'value');

            googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
            googletag.enableServices();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='kvAd'>
        <script>
            googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('kvAd'); });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I test the page, my ROS ads (which have no key values assigned but target all ad units) are showing up. I have been messing with this for a while and cannot figure out why the setTargeting doesn't seem to be working properly to keep non targeted ads out of the key value ad slot.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly logical that your ROS ads are returned. Google DFP will not exclude ads based on setTargeting unless specifically defined in your line-item.

In your line-item, if you were to specify that the ROS should be shown IF "key" is not equal to "value", then the ROS ads would not be shown.

Comment: It sounds like for what I'm wanting to do, then I'll have to either create a "null" value so that if no ads match the key value, then nothing is shown. Or just be ok with the idea of ROS or run of topic ads to fill blank key valued ad slots.

Comment: So does this answer clarify it for you? If so, feel free to accept it, so that it's closed :-)

Comment: Yes, my solution is to run keyed ads at a higher priority to ensure that they show up in those ad slots if they are booked, otherwise they will fall to ad unit > house. Thank you for your clarification.