# DFP reporting free-form key-values, utm_campaign

Tags: javascript, adsense, google-dfp

I want to implement the `utm_campaign` variable in the DFP tag. So, I used the following sources:

[Google DFP: Pass UTM_Source to DFP with javascript (without accessing the DFP Admin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507594/google-dfp-pass-utm-source-to-dfp-with-javascript-without-accessing-the-dfp-ad/44165869#44165869)

[GPT - Non key value ads showing in key valuse ad slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959582/gpt-non-key-value-ads-showing-in-key-valuse-ad-slots)

So I added

```
.setTargeting('utm_campaign', '< ?php echo $_GET['utm_campaign']; ?>');
```

to the code.

But I can't get the reporting to work. I have setup a free-form key-value in the DFP admin, but it is not showing when I run a report. Only the key-values with pre-defined values show up in the reporting.

How can I get the reporting to work, so I can see DFP statistics per `utm_campaign`?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have to add all campaigns to line items or options of the key to get the reporting.